# Does ruby's object_id method refer to the memory location?

Tags: ruby

Or does this method just indicate a unique integer that each object has?

Answer (score 6):

It is a combination of many parameters, value, object type, place in memory.
More can be read [here](http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2006/02/ruby_values_and_object_ids.html)

Answer (score 4):

It isn't a direct reference to the memory location and the "encoding" is specific to a particular Ruby implementation. If you can read C code, you may find it instructive to look at the `rb_obj_id` and `id2ref` methods in `gc.c` in the Ruby 1.8.6 source. You can also read more about the "encoding" in the "Objects embedded in VALUE" section of the partial translation of the [Ruby Hacking Guide chapter 2](http://rhg.rubyforge.org/chapter02.html).

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that you can perform a reverse-lookup of object IDs using:

```
ObjectSpace._id2ref(object_id)
```

For example:

```
ObjectSpace._id2ref(0) #=> false
ObjectSpace._id2ref(1) #=> 0
ObjectSpace._id2ref(2) #=> true
ObjectSpace._id2ref(3) #=> 1
ObjectSpace._id2ref(4) #=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

well, it depends on what you mean by "ruby" ;) In jruby it's just a unique integer as far as I can tell.

Also, things like numbers aren't the memory location. I forget all the details and am sure someone will give them to you.

```
irb(main):020:0> 1.object_id
=> 3 
irb(main):021:0> (2-1).object_id
=> 3
```

Comment: Fixnum are stored in the object_id bit shifted to the left and with the least significant bit set, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402228/accessing-objects-memory-address-in-ruby/2402440#2402440

Your `(2-1)` doesn't make sense, try this instead `(4711>>1).object_id`

Answer (score 1):

In "normal" ruby (MRI 1.8.x and 1.9.x) it's just a unique value.

This is also the case in IronRuby