# Accessing objects memory address in ruby..?

Tags: ruby

Is there any way in Ruby to get the memory address of objects?

```
(i = 5)
```

Is it possible to get the memory address of that object `5`?

I have been trying to get this over some time.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 21):

Yes.

From "[Fiddling with Ruby’s Fiddle](https://medium.com/tech-talk/fiddling-with-rubys-fiddle-39f991dd0565)":

> "You can get the actual pointer value of an object by taking the object id, and doing a bitwise shift to the left. This will give you the pointer (or memory location) of the ruby object in memory."

Using your example of `i = 5` it could be done like so:

```
i = 5
i_ptr_int = i.object_id << 1
=> 22
```

"[In Ruby, why does inspect() print out some kind of object id which is different from what object_id() gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818602/in-ruby-why-does-inspect-print-out-some-kind-of-object-id-which-is-different/2818916#2818916)" has more info about `object_id`, including a brief introduction to the C source underlying the implementation which you might find helpful.

Take a look at "[Fiddle](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/fiddle/rdoc/Fiddle.html)" for some other cool things you can do.

Comment: Not sure why this answer isn't up-voted more, this helps tremendously! If you have `foo =Class.new` then `foo.to_s` returns something like "#<Class:0x007fa49c09e0a0>". Looking at the Ruby source code, this string is assigned to @tmp_classpath. However, once you assign this object to a constant, `Foo = foo`, `foo.to_s` returns "Foo", and @tmp_classpath is removed. I have debug messages both before and after the constant assignment, and can now use `(foo.object_id << 1).to_s(16)` to pair these up.

Answer (score 11):

<strike>[Ruby Memory Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/ruby/memory/feature.html) should be able to pull that off but it's not free.</strike>

Aman Gupta [patched](http://github.com/ice799/memprof/commits/heap_dump) Joe Damatos [memprof](http://github.com/ice799/memprof/) but it seems to be a [work in progress](http://timetobleed.com/what-is-a-ruby-object-introducing-memprof-dump/) and I never got it to run on my machine. Joe has a couple of really good posts about memprof and other low level stuff on his [blog](http://timetobleed.com/).

Now I'm not so sure they really can. Integers are stored as a `Fixnum` and `Fixnum` is not a usual Ruby object, it just looks that way. Ruby uses a clever speed up trick with the `object_id` to make `Fixnum` objects immidiate values. The number is in fact stored in the `object_id` itself. That's why two different Fixnum containing the same value has the same `object_id`.

```
>> x=5
=> 5
>> y=5
=> 5
>> x.object_id
=> 11
>> y.object_id
=> 11
>> z=4711
=> 4711
>> z.object_id
=> 9423
```

The `object_id` of a `Fixnum` is actually created by bit shifting to the left and then setting the least significant bit.

`5` is `0b101` and the `object_id` for `5` is `11` and `11` in binary is `0b1011`.

`4711` is `0b0001001001100111`, shift left and set the bit and you get `0b0010010011001111` and that is 9423 which happens to be the `object_id` for `z` above.

[This behaviour](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/201025) is most probably implementation specific but I don't know of a Ruby implementation that doesn't handle Fixnum this way.

There are at least three more immediate objects in Ruby and that's `false`, `true` and `nil`.

```
>> false.object_id
=> 0
>> true.object_id
=> 2
>> nil.object_id
=> 4
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that in the readme for memprof. I'm also on 32-bit. See above for an explanation how Ruby stores Fixnum.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of a way of having the exact address, but maybe you're looking for something like the `object_id` method?

Extract from its [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-object_id)

> Returns an integer identifier for obj.
>   The same number will be returned on all calls to id for a given object, and no two active objects will share an id

---

Example:

```
> 5.object_id
=> 11
> true.object_id
=> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

[Ruby Memory Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/ruby/memory/index.html) does give you the memory address for the object.

Joe Damato's work (http://timetobleed.com/plugging-ruby-memory-leaks-heapstack-dump-patches-to-help-take-out-the-trash) and (http://timetobleed.com/memprof-a-ruby-level-memory-profiler) is based on the work Software Verification did to create a Ruby memory inspection API (http://www.softwareverify.com/ruby/customBuild/index.html).

Joe describes that on his blog. Therefore Joe's work should also return the appropriate addresses. I'm not fully up to speed with the latest version of Joe's work - he only told me about the first version, not the latest version, but nonetheless, if you are tracking memory allocations in the underpinnings of Ruby, you are tracking the addresses of the objects that hold whatever it is you are allocating.

That doesn't mean you can dereference the address and read the data value you expect to find at that address. Dereferencing the address will point you to the internals of a basic Ruby Object. Ruby objects are a basic object which then store additional data alongside, so knowing the actual address is not very useful unless you are writing a tool like Ruby Memory Validator or memprof.

How do I know the above about Ruby Memory Validator and the API we released? I designed Ruby Memory Validator. I also wrote the assembly language bits that intercept the Ruby calls that allocate the memory.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do?

Keep in mind that a Ruby object is not directly analogous to a variable in a language like C or C++.  For example:

```
a = "foo"
b = a
b[2] = 'b'
b
  => "fob"
a
  => "fob"
a == b
  => true
a.object_id
  => 23924940
b.object_id
  => 23924940
a.object_id == b.object_id
  => true
```

Even through `a` and `b` are separate variables, they are references to the same underlying data and have the same `object_id`.

If you find yourself needing to take the address of a variable, there is probably an easier approach to whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: I just wanted to know how referencing to objects work on ruby, so i thought address will be useful, to get things done..... if there is any better way pls help me...thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to worry about referencing an object in Ruby.  In contrast to other languages where you can pass an object by value or by reference, Ruby handles all the low-level aspects for you.  All you should need to do is use the object and pass it around like you would if you were passing by value in C.  For more information about the internals of Ruby, see http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/language.html.

Answer (score 0):

Since you indicated (buried in a comment somewhere) that you're really just trying to understand how Ruby references things, I think things work as follows:

A `VALUE` in Ruby's C api represents an object (a `nil`, a `FixNum` or a `Boolean`) or a pointer to an `Object`. The `VALUE` contains a 3 bit tag indicating which of these it is, and contains the value (for the first 3) or a direct memory pointer (for an `Object`). There's no way to get at the `VALUE` directly in Ruby, (I'm not sure if the `object_id` is the same or different.)

Note that JRuby operates differently.