# In Ruby, why does inspect() print out some kind of object id which is different from what object_id() gives?

Tags: ruby, object, object-identity

When the `p` function is used to print out an object, it may give an ID, and it is different from what `object_id()` gives.  What is the reason for the different numbers?

**Update:** `0x4684abc` is different from `36971870`, which is `0x234255E`

```
>> a = Point.new
=> #<Point:0x4684abc>

>> a.object_id
=> 36971870

>> a.__id__
=> 36971870

>> "%X" % a.object_id
=> "234255E"
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The default implementation of `inspect` calls the default implementation of `to_s`, which just shows the hexadecimal value of the object directly, as seen in the `Object#to_s` [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-to_s) (click on the method description to reveal the source).

Meanwhile the comments in the C source underlying the implementation of `object_id` shows that there are different “namespaces” for Ruby values and object ids, depending on the type of the object (e.g. the lowest bit seems to be zero for all but Fixnums). You can see that in `Object#object_id` [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-object_id) (click to reveal the source).

From there we can see that in the “object id space” (returned by `object_id`) the ids of objects start from the second bit on the right (with the first bit being zero), but in “value space” (used by `inspect`) they start from the third bit on the right (with the first two bits zero). So, to convert the values from the “object id space” to the “value space”, we can shift the `object_id` to the left by one bit and get the same result that is shown by `inspect`:

```
> '%x' % (36971870 << 1)
=> "4684abc"

> a = Foo.new
=> #<Foo:0x5cfe4>
> '%x' % (a.object_id << 1)
=> "5cfe4"
```

**Note**: The details about `object_id` were correct at the time (2010), but aren't anymore after newer Ruby versions have decoupled `object_id` from memory addresses. Now the answer is more along the lines "because `object_id` is generated on demand". See comments.

Comment: those ruby-doc.org links are dead now :-(

Comment: @AlexChaffee I couldn't find directs links to method sources anymore, edited the post with indirect links.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct for Ruby versions 2.7 and greater. [This blog post](https://jemma.dev/blog/gc-object-id) gives a great explanation. Recent Ruby versions have decoupled `object_id` from the object's actual memory address.

Comment: @ulysses_rex Thanks, you are correct. I have made a note of this in the answer (but left it mostly as it was for historical reference).

Answer (score 0):

```
0x234255E

=>36971870
```

It's not different, it's the hexadecimal representation of the memory address:-)

Comment: 0x4684abc = 2 * 0x234255E, but why? ))

Comment: @aaz: Because `object_id` shifts the object's address to the left by one bit (which is the same as multiplying by two). See my answer for link to source.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby version 2.7 decoupled the object's `object_id` from the memory address itself, so you can't transform an `object_id` into a memory address or vice versa. In fact, the object's actual address can change while its `object_id` remains the same.

That said, depending on your Ruby version, the `ObjectSpace` module might be able to return an object's memory address. Note: this library changes frequently, so most likely you should only use it in the console.

```rb
# Using Ruby version 2.7.8 -- this code may not work in later versions!

require "objspace"
require "json"

object = Object.new
#=> #<Object:0x00007ff174981a08>

object_internals_json = ObjectSpace.dump(object)
#=> "{\"address\":\"0x7ff174981a08\", \"type\":\"OBJECT\", \"class\":\"0x7ff18d991250\", \"ivars\":0, \"memsize\":40, \"flags\":{\"wb_protected\":true}}\n"

JSON.parse(object_internals_json)["address"]
#=> "0x7ff174981a08"
```