# Look up object from `inspect` value / pointer

Tags: ruby

As part of my debugging, I need to dump out a big object. Some of the data shows up like this:

`#<Sketchup::Face:0x00007f9119bafea8>`

This is the result of calling `.inspect` on the `Sketchup::Face` object, and Ruby calls `.inspect` internally when things are printed to the console.

Is it possible to then get a reference to the actual instance, using that `0x00007f9119bafea8` identifier? I don't even know exactly what this is - a pointer, instance id, something else?

Of course I can always manipulate my data before printing to console but since this is just for temporary debugging I'm hoping there's a quick and easy way.

*Note*: normally I would put in a `binding.pry` to avoid this whole business but due to Sketchup's restrictive programming environment it's not possible to use breakpoints there.

Comment: There’s [`ObjectSpace::_id2ref`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-_id2ref) (linking to older docs because the description is missing in the new ones)

Comment: Aye, yeah but `0x00007f9804844a10` isn't an object id

Comment: I’d try to reconstruct the object id (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2818602/477037)). If that doesn’t work, override `inspect` to print the actual object id.

Comment: If my C reading is correct, this is the physical address of the object in the memory. Since ruby has no explicit pointer I'd say it is useless, would be happy to be proven wrong though.

Comment: Combining the information given in the comments above, you can get a refence to the object with a inspect output of `#<Foo:0x000000000d4f07b0>` using `ObjectSpace::_id2ref(0x000000000d4f07b0 >> 1)`