# How do I find a Ruby object in process memory?

Tags: ruby, reverse-engineering

I would like to see how Ruby objects are stored in memory. For example, when I say something like:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

I want to see how that is stored.

The goal is to be able to inspect objects that I do not have the source code to, so I would like to begin with things where the source is readily available.

How can I:

1. Find this array in memory.
2. View it in a hex editor.

Comment: The first part of this is addressed in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2419130/1008891

Comment: Definitely sounds more engaged than I had initially thought. For the purposes of just "figuring out how it is stored" it might be easier to just search for where the data could be in the memory dump.